# Reading complex numbers in comma separated format from a text file into a MATLAB variable

Tags: matlab

I have a text file with complex numbers in the format shown below,

```
(1.00000000,-0.00000000)
(0.66914010,0.74313629)
(-0.10450304,0.99452454)
(-0.80899447,0.58781630)
(-0.97815824,-0.20786168)
(-0.49997231,-0.86604136)
(0.30903524,-0.95105058)
(0.91354805,-0.40673080)
(0.91354805,0.40673080)
(0.30894405,0.95108020)
```

***fscanf(fileID,'%f')*** reads in alternate real and complex part separately, but the final size does not match up. For example my file contains 10,000 complex numbers, so we would expect the output of the scan statement to return 20,000 values, but I'm getting 47,104 values instead.

***fscanf(fileID,'(%f,%f)')*** returns a empty array.

Please suggest the correct single line implementation for the above.

Comment: I've rolled back your changes.  You should definitely leave in the attempts you made because it shows people what you've tried.  Not doing this may make people downvote your question, because it isn't obvious to them that you tried something.  Hope you agree!

Comment: I removed the contact after the blockquotes because it is totally irrelevant. The stuff about getting incorrect number of values is because I was reading the wrong file.

Comment: Ah I see.  OK, it's up to you on whether or not you want to keep my changes.  Either way, I'm glad I helped you solve it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way is to use [`textscan`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html):

```
fid = fopen('file.txt');
out = textscan(fid, '(%f,%f)\n');
result = [out{1} + i*out{2}];
fclose(fid);
```

*Make sure you change `file.txt` to be whatever your text file is named as*.  However, if you are using Windows (thanks Luis Mendo!), you need to change the `\n` delimiter to `\r` to denote a carriage return rather than a newline:

```
fid = fopen('file.txt');
out = textscan(fid, '(%f,%f)\r'); %// Change
result = [out{1} + i*out{2}];
fclose(fid);
```

First open up the file using [`fopen`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fopen.html), then read in the real and imaginary parts as two separate cell arrays.  The `(%f,%f)` formatting string looks for two numbers in between a pair of `()` braces with a comma separating them.  The `\n` (or `\r` if you're using Windows) ensures that we look for only one such pattern per row.

Once you do this, we unpack the first cell and add this with the unpacked second cell and multiplying it by `i` as it's the complex part.  The result will be an array of complex valued numbers.  Make sure you close the file when you're done, and that's done with [`fclose`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fclose.html).

I get the following:

```
>> format long g;
>> result

result =

                          1 +                     0i
                  0.6691401 +            0.74313629i
                -0.10450304 +            0.99452454i
                -0.80899447 +             0.5878163i
                -0.97815824 -            0.20786168i
                -0.49997231 -            0.86604136i
                 0.30903524 -            0.95105058i
                 0.91354805 -             0.4067308i
                 0.91354805 +             0.4067308i
                 0.30894405 +             0.9510802i
```

Comment: This is much simpler!

Comment: I found it. I need to change `\n` into`\r`. I'm on Windows. Perhaps add that to your answer?

Comment: @LuisMendo - Ahhh yes.  I forgot about that lol.  yes, I will add.  Thank you.

Comment: I'm getting empty values in out and result.

Comment: That means that either (1) you're not specifying the right text file name or (2) you didn't format the text file properly.  I'm assuming your text file is of the format you specified in your post.  If it worked for myself and Luis Mendo, then you're doing something wrong.  Also, make sure you see my most recent edit to accommodate for Windows.  I'm on Mac OS and forgot that you need to do `\r` to denote a carriage return rather than `\n` in the format specifier.

Comment: My bad, referred to the wrong file. Works perfectly! thanks!

Comment: @Naveen - No problem at all :) Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

This is probably not the fastest approach, but it's simple:

1. Use [`importdata`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/importdata.html) to read the file. The result is a cell array of strings, each string corresponding to a line of the file.
2. Use [`regexp`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html) to extract the numbers in each line. The result is a cell array of cell arrays. The first level corresponds to lines, the second to numbers detected within each line.
3. Remove one level of cell-nesting to get a cell array of strings (each string representing a number) and apply [`str2double`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/str2double.html) to convert into an array of numbers.
4. Reshape into a two-row array and interpret as real an imaginary parts.

Code:

```
x = importdata('file.txt');                     %// step 1
x = regexp(x, '-?\d+.?\d*', 'match');           %// step 2
x = str2double([x{:}]);                         %// step 3
result = [1 1j]*reshape(x, 2, []);              %// step 4
```

In your example, the result (transposed for clarity) is

```
>> result.'
ans =
  1.000000000000000                     
  0.669140100000000 + 0.743136290000000i
 -0.104503040000000 + 0.994524540000000i
 -0.808994470000000 + 0.587816300000000i
 -0.978158240000000 - 0.207861680000000i
 -0.499972310000000 - 0.866041360000000i
  0.309035240000000 - 0.951050580000000i
  0.913548050000000 - 0.406730800000000i
  0.913548050000000 + 0.406730800000000i
  0.308944050000000 + 0.951080200000000i
```

Comment: I like your use of `regexp`!